# How to set environment variable in bitbake?

Tags: openssl, yocto, bitbake, libcrypto

I'm new to yocto.
While compiling `tpm2`-tools in yocto facing the following issue.

```
checking for CRYPTO... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libcrypto >= 1.0.2g) were not met:

Requested 'libcrypto >= 1.0.2g' but version of OpenSSL-libcrypto is 1.0.2d

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CRYPTO_CFLAGS
and CRYPTO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How and where to set `CRYPTO_CFLAGS` and C`RYPTO_LIBS` as it is mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to modify environment variables: the relevant part of the message is                       this

> Requested 'libcrypto >= 1.0.2g' but version of OpenSSL-libcrypto is
>   1.0.2d

tpm2-tools you are building requires a version of openssl that is not available in your layers.

It's worth investigating why this would happen before you try any fixes: If you just use *compatible branches* of various layers this should not happen (I'm assuming the recipes are unmodified by you -- do mention if that's not case). So check the layers providing openssl and tpm2-tools: are you using the same branch for each layer?

If you mention your layers (and the branch you're using) in your question someone might be able to give more specific advice.